# Passing parameter from link_to to controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, parameters, controller, link-to

How can I pass `subscription.title` to my controller method `watchsub`? How do you then access the variable in `watchsub`?

In my view I have

```
<% @subscriptions.each do |subscription| %>
              <tr>
                <td> <%= link_to subscription.title, watchsub_stream_path(subscription.title), :method => :get %> </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First all you'll need a **post** request not a **get** as you want to send something. You have to make a route in your routes.rb file for you custom action like:

```
post "/sub/:id" => your_controller#watchsub , as: :watchsub    #Here id will be your subscription id
```

then you can make your link like this:

```
<%= link_to subscription.title, watchsub_path(subscription.id), :method => :post %>
```

and inside your watchsub method you can access that particular subscription by doing something  like:

```
@subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
```

This will give you more flexibility as you'll have your subscription and you can access all its attributes for example if you want title then you can simply do

```
@subscription.title
```